# fork system command creates number of unexpected number of process

Tags: c

```
   #include <unistd.h>
   int main()
    { 
      fork();
      fork() && fork() || fork();
      fork();  
      printf(“forked\n”);
      return 0;
    }
```

Please help me out to understand this program. Why it is printing 20 times?

Comment: `2 * (2 * 2 + 1) * 2 = 20`

Comment: Not the very best question. But -5? Keep calm, people. I've seen worse ones.

Comment: There probably are duplicates, and downvotes might be because of "I can't be bothered to search for duplicate, so I'll just downvote"... And close votes for failing to describe the problem, really?

Answer (score 1):

Now remember, each `fork()` call results in a new process being created, and return value in one process is 0, and a positive value (pid, but this is irrelevant here) in the other. So if you have code

```
fork(); fork(); fork();
```

you end up with 8 processes. Original one, the child created by first fork, then for both of these, a child created by the 2nd fork (now total 4), then for all 4 of these, one more child created by the 3rd fork.

Then consider the clarified version of the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h> // to have bool type for correct code
int main()
{ 
    fork();

    // (fork() && fork()) || fork() opened up
    {
        bool tmp = fork(); // 0 implicitly cast to false, nonzero to true
        if (tmp) {
            tmp = fork();
        }
        if (!tmp) {
            tmp = fork();
        }
    }

    fork();  
    printf(“forked\n”);
    return 0;
}
```

So this adds up to 20 processes being spawned, and each one will eventually reach the `printf`. How exactly, you can work that through in your head (use paper and pen to help) if you want the brain excercise, doing it with debugger is an excercise in futility thanks to all the forks.

Answer (score 1):

Every fork leads to two processes, essentially.

In the expression `fork() && fork() || fork();`, not each of the `fork()` calls is executed.

A `fork()` call returns in the caller process with the PID of che child and in the new child process with 0.

If this line is executed in any process A, the first one leads to one new process B. The line is continued in both processes. The second one will be executed in A, but not in B. So A gets a new child C. The third one is executed in B and in C, but not in A, leading to D and E.

So we get 5 processes for this line.

This line is executed in 2 processes, as the preceding `fork();` on a single line leads to them.

Now we have 10 processes, each executing the final `fork();` so that we get 20 processes.

Instead of

```
printf("forked\n");
```

you could do

```
printf("forked %d <- %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
```

to see the relationship between the processes.

Answer (score 0):

refer this:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fork-and-binary-tree/

Idea is keep in mind that - fork() return 0 in child process and non-zero(child process PID) in parent process. And conditional operators are shorthand.

Comment: `fork()` returns 1 only in very rare cases (if at all).